# PHP: global внутри функции не показывает переменную

Tags: php, php7, global-variables

Опишу ситуацию.

В теле метода класса подключается файл ($dataFile):

```
public function method()
{
    $data = include_once $dataFile;
    $content = $this->renderFile($template, $data);
}
```

В подключаемом файле следующая логика:

```
$lang = dolang();
// code...

while ($country = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // code...

    $countries[] = [
       // code...
       'name'        => $name,
       'title'       => getCountryTitle($name)
    ];
}

return compact('countries');

function getCountryTitle(string $name) {
    global $lang;
    return str_replace('%COUNTRY%', sklon($name), $lang['catalog_meta_title_country']);
}
```

Этот подключаемый файл последовательно выполняет код используя некоторые функции объявленные в нём же и в конце возвращает некий результат.

И вот проблема в том, что внутри функции `getCountryTitle` глобальная переменная `$lang` не видна, она `null` соответственно.
Аналогично с другими переменными и другими функциями.

Смотрю под отладчиком - при выполнении логики в файле не заходя в функцию глобальные переменные инициализированы и всё хорошо. При заходе в функцию и объявляя их глобальными - они невидимы.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: dolang() где определена?

Comment: В другом подключаемом файле. Я же писал, что $lang  (результат dolang) инициализируются правильно, но внутри других функций переменная не видна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь следует отметить, что представленный вами элемент кода следует рассматривать, как **плохой стиль проектирования и программирования**, поскольку он рассматривает подключаемый файл как моментально выполняемый набор операций.

Наиболее правильный подход заключался бы в том, чтобы поместить набор операций в виде функций/класса с собственным именем в файл, подключить файл (без какого-либо оператора возврата за пределами функций), а затем вызывать функцию **явно** с требуемым набором аргументов.

### Так в чем проблема-то?

Все предельно просто, вы делаете **include** внутри метода **method**, а значит переменные указанные в подключаемом файле инициализируются в области видимости метода **method**. Следовательно, переменная **$lang** не является глобальной, **а ограничена видимостью метода**, а вы обращаетесь к глобальной переменной, поэтому при использовании модификатора **global** она будет равна null.

Если делать include в глобальной области видимости, тогда переменная lang станет общедоступной (global) и ее использование станет возможным. Это легко проверить, достаточно в подключаемом файле перед началом определения какой-либо переменной написать **global $переменная.**

### Пример:

```
include 'file1.php';

function include2() {
  include 'file2.php';
}
```

- file1.php определен в глобальной области видимости.
- file2.php определен в локальной области видимости функции include2.

Подход с глобальными переменными и таким include - это костыль, который принесет вам проблем в будущем. Функции должны быть определены явно, иметь уникальное имя и выполняться по требованию.

### А почему подход с глобальными переменными плохой?

Дело в том, что глобальные переменные видимы отовсюду, глобально. Это удобно: ведь нет никаких ограничителей. С другой стороны, становится совершенно невозможно отследить, кто меняет данные. Неконтролируемые изменения - это первое, что обычно приходит в голову на вопрос о том, чем же плохи глобальные переменные.

Предположим, у вас есть функция, результат которой зависит от глобальной переменной. Вы вызываете её, вызываете - но через 10 минут функция начинает возвращать неверные результаты. Что случилось? Ведь на вход вы передаёте ей всё тот же набор параметров? Гм, кто-то поменял значение глобальной переменной... Кто это мог быть? Да кто угодно - ведь глобальная переменная доступна всем..

Лучший рецепт при проектировании подпрограмм: **сделать так, чтобы результат вашей функции зависел бы только от аргументов**. Это идеал, к которому нужно стремиться.

**Не используйте глобальные переменные в проекте без необходимости**, пользуйтесь всеми возможностями локальной области видимости, передачи параметров в аргументы функции и код будет легче писать, поддерживать и тестировать.

---

Знаете какой наилучший префикс для глобальных переменных?

**Ответ:** //